# Combine 3 lists of dicts using uid

Tags: python, list, dictionary, uid

I have three lists of dicts, some sample data can look like:

```
list_1.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2}, {"id": "555", "opens": 2}]})
list_1.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2}, {"id": "555", "opens": 3}]})

list_2.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "clicks": 1}, {"id": "555", "clicks": 2}]})
list_2.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "clicks": 3}, {"id": "555", "clicks": 3}]})

list_3.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "bounces": 2}, {"id": "555", "bounces": 1}]})
list_3.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "bounces": 3}, {"id": "555", "bounces": 2}]})
```

Using the shared id and ids on the users I want to create 1 combined list that looks like:

```
combined_list.append([{"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2, "clicks": 1, "bounces": 2, "combined_id": 444111}, {"id": "555", "opens": 3, "clicks": 2, "bounces": 1, "combined_id": 555111}}])

combined_list.append([{"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2, "clicks": 3, "bounces": 1, "combined_id": 444222}, {"id": "555", "opens": 3, "clicks": 3, "bounces": 2, "combined_id": 555222}}])
```

I have solved it when I had 2 lists using nested for loops, but the code is super messy and does not feel very pythonized, is there a better way now that I am using 3 lists?

```
for o in list_1:
        for c in list_2:
            if o['shared_id'] == c['shared_id']:
                csd = {
                    'users': [],
                    'shared_id': o['shared_id']
                }
                for op in o['users']:
                    for cp in c['users']:
                        if op['id'] == cp['id']:
                            cpd = {
                                'opens': op['opens'],
                                'clicks': cp['clicks'],
                                'combined_id': '{}{}'.format(
                                    op['id'],
                                    csd['shared_id']
                                    )
                            }

                            csd['users'].append(cpd)

                combined.append(csd)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: Your code and desired output do not match. Do you need that `'combined_id'`? The "best" solution also depends on details. You might want to input data into a pandas dataframe first if you do anything else with it besides comvining lists.

Comment: @IcedLance Ah good catch, sorry. I do need it yes, will add it to my edit.

Comment: For simple solution you can move you code to a separate function `def combine(a,b)` but replace `cpd=•••` part with `cpd={**op, **cp, 'combined_id': xx+x}` . But that's just a shortcut, it replaces duplicate entries (but you make sure they are the same. If you want anything more like sum the values with same key you shoyld look into pandas.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) for grouping elements:

```
list_1, list_2, list_3 = [], [], []

list_1.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2}, {"id": "555", "opens": 2}]})
list_1.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2}, {"id": "555", "opens": 3}]})

list_2.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "clicks": 1}, {"id": "555", "clicks": 2}]})
list_2.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "clicks": 3}, {"id": "555", "clicks": 3}]})

list_3.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "bounces": 2}, {"id": "555", "bounces": 1}]})
list_3.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "bounces": 3}, {"id": "555", "bounces": 2}]})

from itertools import groupby

shared_ids = {}
for v, g in groupby(sorted(list_1 + list_2 + list_3, key=lambda k: k['shared_id']), lambda k: k['shared_id']):
    for shared_id in g:
        for user in shared_id['users']:
            shared_ids.setdefault(v, {}).setdefault(user['id'], {}).update(**user)
            shared_ids[v][user['id']]['combined_id'] = '{}{}'.format(user['id'], v)


out = [{'shared_id': k, 'users': [shared_ids[k][kk] for kk in shared_ids[k]]} for k in shared_ids]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'shared_id': '111',
  'users': [{'bounces': 2, 'clicks': 1, 'combined_id': '444111', 'id': '444', 'opens': 2},
            {'bounces': 1, 'clicks': 2, 'combined_id': '555111', 'id': '555', 'opens': 2}]},
 {'shared_id': '222',
  'users': [{'bounces': 3, 'clicks': 3, 'combined_id': '444222', 'id': '444', 'opens': 2},
            {'bounces': 2, 'clicks': 3, 'combined_id': '555222', 'id': '555', 'opens': 3}]}]
```

NOTE: If you print `shared_ids` variable, you get:

```
{'111': {'444': {'bounces': 2, 'clicks': 1, 'combined_id': '444111', 'id': '444', 'opens': 2},
         '555': {'bounces': 1, 'clicks': 2, 'combined_id': '555111', 'id': '555', 'opens': 2}},
 '222': {'444': {'bounces': 3, 'clicks': 3, 'combined_id': '444222', 'id': '444', 'opens': 2},
         '555': {'bounces': 2, 'clicks': 3, 'combined_id': '555222', 'id': '555', 'opens': 3}}}
```

Maybe this dictionary will be better to manipulate further.

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple function for that:

```
from pprint import pprint

def combine_lists(*lists):
    result = {}
    # For each list
    for lst in lists:
        # For each dict in the list
        for d1 in lst:
            # Get or make common dict for shared_id
            shared_id = d1["shared_id"]
            shared_dict = result.setdefault(shared_id, {})
            # For each user dict in the dict
            for d2 in d1["users"]:
                # Get or make user dict
                user_id = d2["id"]
                if user_id not in shared_dict:
                    shared_dict[user_id] = {"combined_id": "{}{}".format(user_id, shared_id)}
                # Update information in user dictionary
                shared_dict[user_id].update(d2)
    # Make output as a list
    return [{"shared_id": k, "users": list(v.values())} for k, v in result.items()]

# Test
list_1 = []
list_1.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2}, {"id": "555", "opens": 2}]})
list_1.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2}, {"id": "555", "opens": 3}]})
list_2 = []
list_2.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "clicks": 1}, {"id": "555", "clicks": 2}]})
list_2.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "clicks": 3}, {"id": "555", "clicks": 3}]})
list_3 = []
list_3.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "bounces": 2}, {"id": "555", "bounces": 1}]})
list_3.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "bounces": 3}, {"id": "555", "bounces": 2}]})

pprint(combine_lists(list_1, list_2, list_3))
# [{'shared_id': '111',
#   'users': [{'bounces': 2,
#              'clicks': 1,
#              'combined_id': '444111',
#              'id': '444',
#              'opens': 2},
#             {'bounces': 1,
#              'clicks': 2,
#              'combined_id': '555111',
#              'id': '555',
#              'opens': 2}]},
#  {'shared_id': '222',
#   'users': [{'bounces': 3,
#              'clicks': 3,
#              'combined_id': '444222',
#              'id': '444',
#              'opens': 2},
#             {'bounces': 2,
#              'clicks': 3,
#              'combined_id': '555222',
#              'id': '555',
#              'opens': 3}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the ids together, then [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/244297) the dictionaries as needed:

```
from collections import ChainMap
from itertools import chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

combined_list = []
for k, g in groupby(sorted(chain(list_1, list_2, list_3), key=itemgetter('shared_id')), key=itemgetter('shared_id')):
    users = []
    for k2, g2 in groupby(sorted(chain(*map(itemgetter('users'), g)), key=itemgetter('id')), key=itemgetter('id')):
        users.append({'id': k2, 'combined_id': k2 + k, **ChainMap(*g2)})

    combined_list.append({'shared_id': k, 'users': users})
print(combined_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'shared_id': '111', 'users': [{'id': '444', 'combined_id': '444111', 'bounces': 2, 'clicks': 1, 'opens': 2}, {'id': '555', 'combined_id': '555111', 'bounces': 1, 'clicks': 2, 'opens': 2}]}, {'shared_id': '222', 'users': [{'id': '444', 'combined_id': '444222', 'bounces': 3, 'clicks': 3, 'opens': 2}, {'id': '555', 'combined_id': '555222', 'bounces': 2, 'clicks': 3, 'opens': 3}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Objected Oriented Solution

```
# Data structure to manage shared object information
class shared(object):
  def __init__(self, i):
    self.i = i
    self.users = dict()

  # Add information of the particulate user
  def update_user(self, user_id, key, value):
    if user_id in self.users:
      self.users[user_id][key] = value
    else:
      self.users[user_id]= {key:value,
                            "id":user_id, 
                            "combined_id": "{0}{1}".format(user_id,self.i)}      

  # Return the information is required format
  def get(self):
    return  {
        'shared_id': self.i,
        'users' : [ user for user in self.users.values()]
    }
```

**Data**

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []

list_1.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2}, {"id": "555", "opens": 2}]})
list_1.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2}, {"id": "555", "opens": 3}]})

list_2.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "clicks": 1}, {"id": "555", "clicks": 2}]})
list_2.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "clicks": 3}, {"id": "555", "clicks": 3}]})

list_3.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "bounces": 2}, {"id": "555", "bounces": 1}]})
list_3.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "bounces": 3}, {"id": "555", "bounces": 2}]})
```

**Parse the Data**

```
info = {}
for l in list_1+list_2+list_3:
  # Is there already information for this shared_id ?
  if l["shared_id"] not in info:
    info[l["shared_id"]] = shared(l["shared_id"])
  # Parse all the users  
  for user_info in l['users']:
    user_id = user_info["id"]
    # Parse the user information
    for key,value in user_info.items():
      if key != "id":
        # Update the user information
        info[l["shared_id"]].update_user(user_id, key, value)


result = [x.get() for x in info.values()]
print (result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'shared_id': '111', 'users': [{'opens': 2, 'id': '444', 'combined_id': '444111', 'clicks': 1, 'bounces': 2}, {'opens': 2, 'id': '555', 'combined_id': '555111', 'clicks': 2, 'bounces': 1}]}, 
 {'shared_id': '222', 'users': [{'opens': 2, 'id': '444', 'combined_id': '444222', 'clicks': 3, 'bounces': 3}, {'opens': 3, 'id': '555', 'combined_id': '555222', 'clicks': 3, 'bounces': 2}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global_list = []

def add_item(item):
    item_found = False
    for e_item in global_list:
        if e_item['shared_id'] == item['shared_id']:
            item_found = True
            e_users = e_item['users']
            users = item['users']
            for user in users:
                user_found = False
                for e_user in e_users:
                    if e_user['id'] == user['id']:
                        user_found = True
                        e_user.update(user)
                if user_found is False:
                    e_users.append(user)
    if item_found is False:
        global_list.append(item)    



list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []

list_1.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2}, {"id": "555", "opens": 2}]})
list_1.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "opens": 2}, {"id": "555", "opens": 3}]})

list_2.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "clicks": 1}, {"id": "555", "clicks": 2}]})
list_2.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "clicks": 3}, {"id": "555", "clicks": 3}]})

list_3.append({"shared_id": "111", "users": [{"id": "444", "bounces": 2}, {"id": "555", "bounces": 1}]})
list_3.append({"shared_id": "222", "users": [{"id": "444", "bounces": 3}, {"id": "555", "bounces": 2}]})

for item in list_1+list_2+list_3:
    add_item(item)
print(global_list)
```